# Reading images from multiple folders / subfolders to perform various PIL functions

Tags: python

Problem: It looks like the glob/PIL doesn't read images in subfolders. Is there a way to apply this to multiple directories/subfolders?

Purpose: List all the images in a directory, which has multiple folders (subfolders), by their name and size (resolution). I've used PIL/glob and so far, this has worked well on a single folder. However, when I try to apply the same logic on a folder that has over 1000 subfolders, the list returns no value.

Here is the code I've written using PIL, glob, and os:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os

im=[]

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    print(file, im.size)
```

The above code lists all the images in this format - e.g., NYC (3795, 1588).

I'd appreciate your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You should use pathlib, it's nice.

Comment: will give a try, AMC. Still at the very beginning stage of learning. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With a directory tree like this:

```
.
└── dirA
    ├── dirB
    │   ├── fileA
    │   └── fileB
    ├── fileA
    └── fileB
```

Using recursive glob you are able to get the result you want:

```py
>>> from glob import glob
>>> glob('./**/*', recursive=True)
['./dirA', './dirA/fileA', './dirA/fileB', './dirA/dirB', './dirA/dirB/fileA', './dirA/dirB/fileB']
```

> `**`: recursively match any number of layers of non-hidden directories
>
> `*`: matches any number of any characters including none
>
> [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Comment: thank you, Gustavo!